# Rocket Chat build successfully throwing error on run

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am not getting this errors, when i run rocket chat source code after successful build it giving me following error:

Here's [https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.Android]  reference source code link.

```
 error: State is not public in kotlin.collections; cannot be accessed from outside package private final java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList<kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.Channel<kotlin.collections.State>> statusChannelList = null;

error: State is not public in kotlin.collections; cannot be accessed from outside package public final androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData<kotlin.collections.State> getStatusLiveData() {

error: State is not public in kotlin.collections; cannot be accessed from outside package kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.Channel<kotlin.collections.State> channel) {         
error: State is not public in kotlin.collections; cannot be accessed from outside package kotlin.collections.State state);    

error: State is not public in kotlin.collections; cannot be accessed from outside package
 private kotlin.collections.State lastState;

error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public final class ChatRoomPresenter {

error: State is not public in kotlin.collections; cannot be accessed from outside package
public final androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData<kotlin.collections.State> getStatus() {   

error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public final class ChatRoomsFragment extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment implements chat.rocket.android.chatrooms.presentation.ChatRoomsView {
```

Comment: Pick one error, google it and try to understand what it means. That's the best way to learn.

Comment: I already did that after not getting the solution i posted here.

Comment: These are compile-time errors, not runtime errors.

Comment: ok so how can i solve this